# Set Up C++ project with Atom

Tags: c++, atom-editor

I'm trying set up cpp project with Atom. My project (Picture below). My code (Snippets below). I get error `undefined reference to hashCustom::Hash(std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. I did everything from tutorial, in one difference, that tutor used Visual Studio, but it doesn't support Linux. How I can rid error?

#### `hash.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef HASH_H
#define HASH_H

class hashCustom {
  public:
  int Hash(string key);
};

#endif
```

#### `hash.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "../Header Files/hash.h"
using namespace std;

int hashCustom::Hash(string key) {
  int index;
  index = key.length();
  return index;
}
```

#### `main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "../Header Files/hash.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {

  hashCustom hashObj;
  cout << hashObj.Hash("Number") << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Remove this line: `using namespace std;` as there is also a `std::hash`.  Or use `::hash` to refer to your your hash class.  see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash

Comment: @RichardCritten now I get error `‘template<class _Tp> struct std::hash’ used without template parameters`

Comment: On any particular line? This is relevant information included in the error which you're withholding.

Comment: Exactly what change did you make? As that error means you are now trying to use `std::hash`  which is not what I suggested,

Comment: Did you perhaps remove only _one_ of the two `using namepace std` lines? Neither should be there.

Comment: @RichardCritten I updated question

Comment: How do you compile that program? What does the command line look like? Are you linking hash.cpp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message you posted, it seems that the linker can't resolve that symbol. You should compile both `main.cpp` and `hash.cpp` together, with a command like (using gcc):

```
$ g++ -o test main.cpp hash.cpp
```

Working example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/PIK8kF4eINcLjEYc

Otherwise, you get the same error: https://wandbox.org/permlink/K8nmaUmJZhlS8Wml